# Activate Windows on many PCs with different FPP Serials

Tags: windows, file-io, vbscript, batch-processing, activation

I am writing a script to automate the activation of 200 hundreds PCs like using a Volume Licensing Key, But the case here is The serials are for Full Packaged Product.

1. Used a text file for storing serial numbers one per line.
2. Read a 29 chars (serial)
3. Call slmgr to install the key and then activate it.
4. Add to the line "Used Key" to indicate that it was consumed.

I currently have this code:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim objFSO, objTextFile
Dim sRead, sReadLine, sReadAll
Const ForReading = 1, ForAppending = 8

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\SN.txt", ForReading)
sRead = objTextFile.Read(29)
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "slmgr.vbs -ipk " & sRead
objShell.Run "slmgr.vbs -ato"
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\SN.txt", ForAppending, True)
objTextFile.Write (" Used Key.")
objTextFile.Close
```

The problem is how to use this script once on each PC, i.e. skip to the next line when the script is executed on another PC.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your environment. Are the computers member of a domain? Do you run the script locally or remotely? Does the file with your product keys contain just 1 key per line, or is there anything else in it? Besides, for 200 PCs you seriously should get an actual volume license key.

Comment: `wmic /node:@"computername.txt" process call create "wscript scriptname.vbs"` VBS can also run commands on other computers. See `wshremote`. `WMIC /?` and search goggle for WshRemote (although it is in the VBS docs which you should have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me whether your question is about how to handle the product keys, or also about how to run the script on each computer. For the latter you'd need to provide more information about your environment, so in this answer I'm addressing just the key handling.

The product key handling could be implemented by using different files for used and unused keys. First you read the available keys into an appropriate data structure (e.g. an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
basedir    = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptName)
unusedKeys = objFSO.BuildPath(basedir, "SN.txt")

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(unusedKeys, ForReading)
Set keys = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  keys.Add objTextFile.ReadLine
Loop
objTextFile.Close
```

Retrieve a key from the list and record it in the "used product keys" file:

```
If keys.Count > 0 Then
  productKey = keys(0)
  keys.RemoveAt(0)
  usedKeys = objFSO.BuildPath(basedir, "used-sn.txt")
  objFSO.OpenTextFile(usedKeys, ForAppending, True).WriteLine productKey
Else
  WScript.Echo "No product key available."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Write the remaining unused keys back to the original file:

```
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(unusedKeys, 2)
For Each key In keys
  objTextFile.WriteLine key
Loop
objTextFile.Close
```

Comment: I am currently using the key file to activate each pc by plugging an USBDrive d:\ with a keys text file "sn.txt" and the script, after each execution i remove the used key and put it in another text file "used-sn.txt" manually, i am looking further to automate all the task as i can.

Comment: @madoui20032003: The above code snippets should do that for you. I modified them to make the code look for the data files in the same folder as the script (in case the USB drive is mounted to a different drive letter than D:).

Comment: it's accepted as a solution; thank you very much. can you suggest other optimizations or another approach ?

Comment: When executed with Admin Privileges the basedir will be %windir%\System32 ???? how to redirect it to the root of USB Drive?

Comment: @madoui20032003 That's probably because you re-run the script via `ShellExecute`. Change the 3rd parameter of that method from `""` to `basedir` (and of course move the definition of `basedir` before that).

Comment: even with basedir as third parameter and of course the definition is moved before that. process monitor indicates that wscript is searching for c:\windows\system32\sn.txt 
i changed GetParentFolderName with this manip
basedir = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName))) and it works

Comment: @madoui20032003 That doesn't make any sense. Did you instantiate `objFSO` before calling `GetParentFolderName()`?

Comment: sorry it's my fault, i didn't instantiate it.